# A-Camera Still moves though a-mixin after static-body has been applied

Tags: html, aframe

So, I'm adding aframe physics ([this one](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras)) and when I apply static-body to the a-mixin voxel on the Minecraft demo I can still move through the box.

My camera is set to universal-controls.

Here is where I put the static body:

```
    <a-assets>
       <a-mixin id="voxel" 
         static-body geometry="primitive: box; height: 0.6; width:0.6; 
         depth: 0.6" material="id: theImage; src: Box.jpg; color: 
         #696969; roughness: 1; metalness: 0" 
         snap="offset: 0.4 0.4 0.4; snap: 0.6 0.6 0.6">
       </a-mixin>
    </a-assets>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using [aframe-extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls#usage) (physics-based movement section) and [aframe-physics](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system) if you set up your camera in a `rig` with a `kinematic-body`:

```
<a-entity id="rig" movement-controls kinematic-body>
   <a-entity camera position="0 1.6 0" look-controls></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

It should collide with any entities, that are either `static-body` or `dynamic-body`.

```
<a-box static-body></a-box>
<a-box dynamic-body></a-box>
```

- Custom fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/ejapuqgm/). Dynamic, and static bodies.
- Minecraft demo [here](https://glitch.com/~aframe-aincraft-wphysics). If you make a 3x1 pole, you won't move through it. You'll "jump" over the 2x1 blocks though.

Comment: I'd have to see it on a glitch or somewhere, is it possible the plane is too small ?